# Display song's metadata in page title (browser tab)?

Tags: javascript, metadata, jsonp

I would label my coding skills as intermediate thus what I am asking may or may not be simple or obvious (I wouldn't know the difference). Also I sincerely thank any and everyone who gives this even an ounce of attention.

My objective is to grab raw song metadata from another server (in which I am a client of) via the jsonp and ajax method. Once I successfully obtain the metadata (Artist, Title & album), **I then would like to display it in my website’s page title** (please see pics below).
The reason I would like to do this is because from what I could gather via an extensive and worn out research, it seems that most Bluetooth Audio devices are reading the metadata from the page title (browser tab):
[Google Music playing in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC2Xq.jpg) 
[BT Audio player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCUkV.jpg)

What I would love to do seems like it should be simple to do, yet I cannot figure away to display "Artist, Title and Album" in my browser like Spotify, Youtube or Google Music does.

My code below is able to pull the raw data, convert it using jsonp and I can successfully push only ONE element from the raw data (IE 'title') by placing it as an ID element. However, how can I push all three (Artist, Title & Album) to the page title?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    lang=en
    dir="ltr"
    class="mobile-web-player"
>

<head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
<script type="text/javascript">      
         function update(metadataObj) {
            if (metadataObj && metadataObj.m_Item2) {
               
               var title = document.getElementById('title');
               title.innerHTML = metadataObj.m_Item2.Title;
               
               var artist = document.getElementById('artist');
               artist.innerHTML = 'by ' +   metadataObj.m_Item2.Artist;

               var album = document.getElementById('album');
               album.innerHTML = metadataObj.m_Item2.Album + ' ';
              
            }
         }         
</script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var stationID = 'X123';
            var apiToken = 'X12345';
            // refresh MetaData every 5 seconds
         function fetchMetadata(stationID, apiToken) {            
            $.ajax({
               type: 'get',
               cache: false,
               url: "https://listen.samcloud.com/webapi/station/X123/history/npe?token=X12345&callback=update&format=json",
               //async: true,
               datatype: 'jsonp',
            });
         }
         fetchMetadata(stationID, apiToken);
         window.setInterval(function() {
            fetchMetadata(stationID, apiToken);
         }, 5000);
      </script>

<!-- I can successfully send the song's title to my page title via <title id> method -->
<title id="title">My Radio Station</title>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried this in your update method? title.innerHTML = metadataObj.m_Item2.Artist + ' - ' + metadataObj.m_Item2.Title + ' - ' + metadataObj.m_Item2.Album;

Comment: That did work, it is exactly what I asked for. But everything was just on one line vs like in the screenshot of my radio device when playing google music (Title of song is placed in the middle, artist below and album at the very bottom). Is there away I can indicate where the Album, Artists and Title is placed inside of the page title? I know that probably doesn't make a lick of sense... :-(

Comment: yes, we can modify how they appear. how exactly do you want it to appear? I'll update my answer below.

Comment: Can you have another look at the two pics in my post, I updated them to indicate exactly what I am trying to duplicate. The "Google Music playing in browser" image is a screenshot of my tab while playing a song in google music. The "Bluetooth Audio Device" is the result of me playing that same song via my car radio. The "Album, Artist & Title" are definitely being pushed to my BT device through the page title info, but all I can get to display is one element (Album, Artist or Title) rather than all three.

Comment: I modified my answer to show the data in the order you want, but I've had no luck in inserting line breaks into the browser tabs title.

Comment: Thank you for trying brother, I surely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update()` function you can call `document.title` to set the new tab title instead of setting the `<title>` tag. For example:

```
function update(metadataObj) {
  if (metadataObj && metadataObj.m_Item2) {

     var title = document.getElementById('title');
     var artist = document.getElementById('artist');
     var album = document.getElementById('album');
     // If you are using es6
     document.title = `Playing ${title} from ${artist} - ${album}`;
     // If not using es6
     // document.title = 'Playing '+ title + ' from '+ artist +' - album';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you have another look at the two pics in my post, I updated them to indicate exactly what I am trying to duplicate. The "Google Music playing in browser" image is a screenshot of my tab while playing a song in google music. The "Bluetooth Audio Device" is the result of me playing that same song via my car radio. The "Album, Artist & Title" are definitely being pushed to my BT device through the page title info, but all I can get to display is one element (Album, Artist or Title) rather than all three.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your update function to the following to write Artist, Title, and Album to the web pages title.

```
function update(metadataObj) {
  if (metadataObj && metadataObj.m_Item2) {               
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
     title.innerHTML = metadataObj.m_Item2.Title + ' ' + metadataObj.m_Item2.Album + ' ' + metadataObj.m_Item2.Artist;              
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you have another look at the two pics in my post, I updated them to indicate exactly what I am trying to duplicate. The "Google Music playing in browser" image is a screenshot of my tab while playing a song in google music. The "Bluetooth Audio Device" is the result of me playing that same song via my car radio. The "Album, Artist & Title" are definitely being pushed to my BT device through the page title info, but all I can get to display is one element (Album, Artist or Title) rather than all three.